# Installing tun module without kernel source

Tags: linux, openvpn, kernel, compile, kernel-module

I have a Verizon Mifi 5510L that I'd like to run an OpenVPN client on (I can't run it on my iPad because my school won't let me). I managed to get a shell and get root on it and I can get files to it with `curl` but, even if I figure out how to cross compile OpenVPN, I won't be able to run it since the device doesn't have the `tun` module.

[This tutorial that I was using](http://bengreen.eu/fancyhtml/techiestuff/crosscompileopenvpnformybook.html) has instructions for compiling the kernel with `tun` but, as far as I know, Novatel hasn't complied with the GPL and released the source. Is there any other way I can get `tun` installed without it?